# Can I change one annotation to another annotation in Spring?

Tags: spring

Can someone explain can we replace annotation to another annotation in Spring?

I searched about it so I only found that @Autowired and @Inject we can replace but still its having a difference.

I think we can't replace annotation with other annotation?

Is it correct?

Comment: Do you mean renaming the actual spring annotations? You could extend existing annotations and build upon them before using them in your app.

Comment: @Maki , replacing annotations

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't have a problem by replacing one another. As @Inject was introduced in JSR-330.

For example you have the component:

```
@Component
public class ArbitraryDependency {

    private final String label = "Arbitrary Dependency";

    public String toString() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

injecting the bean like:

```
@Inject
ArbitraryDependency arbitraryDependency;
```

will have no difference by injecting it like:

```
@Autowired
ArbitraryDependency arbitraryDependency;
```

[More about key differences](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-annotations-resource-inject-autowire)

Comment: I am asking about all the annotations in spring , whether it can be replaced by some another annotation ?

Comment: Which annotations? For example `@Configuration`? When you should want something like that, you should build that or extend it as @Maki said. And really, I find no perpose for something like this.